# How to store the result of a linq query in a KeyDictionary variable

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a collection of objects who have multiple properties, two of these are groupname and personname. Now I need to count in the collection how many of each object belong to a certain group and person. So in other words, I need to group by groupname, then personname and then count how many objects have this combination. First I created this

```
public MultiKeyDictionary<string, string, int> GetPersonsPerGroup(IEnumerable<Home> homes ,List<string> gr, List<string> na)
        {
            List<string> groups = gr;
            groups.Add("");
            List<string> names = na;
            names.Add("");
            List<Home> Filtered = homes.ToList();
            Filtered.ForEach(h => h.RemoveNull());
            var result = new MultiKeyDictionary<string, string, int>();
        int counter1 = 0;
foreach (var g in groups)
    {
        int counter2 = 0;
        foreach (var n in names)
        { 
            int counter3 = 0;
            foreach (Home h in Filtered)
            {
                if (h.GroupName == g && h.PersonName == n)
                {
                    counter3++;
                    if (counter3 > 100)
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (counter3 > 0)
            {
                result.Add(g,n,counter3);
            }
            counter2++;
        }
        counter1++;

    }
```

Which may look good, but the problem is that the "home" parameter can contain more than 10000 objects, with more than 1500 unique names and around 200 unique groups. Which causes this to iterate like a billion times really slowing my program down. So I need an other way of handling this. Which made me decide to try using linq. Which led to this creation:

```
var newList = Filtered.GroupBy(x => new { x.GroupName, x.PersonName })
                .Select(y => (MultiKeyDictionary<string, string, int>)result.Add(y.Key.GroupName, y.Key.PersonName, y.ToList().Count));
```

Which gives an error `"Cannot convert type     '`void`'     to     'MultiKeyDictionary<string,string,int>'`     and I have no idea how to solve it. How can I make it so that the result of this query gets stored all in one MultikeyDictionary without having to iterate over each possible combination and counting all of them.

Some information:

- `MultiKeyDictionary`     is a class I defined (something I found on here actually), it's just a normal dictionary but with two keys assosiated to one value.
- The     `RemoveNull()`     method on the Home object makes sure that all the properties of the Home object are not null. If it is the case the value gets sets to something not `null` (`"null", basic date, 0, ...`).
- The parameters are:
  `homes = a` list of Home objects received from an other class
  gr = a list of all the unique groups in the list of homes 
  na = a list of all the unique names in the list of homes
- The same name can occur on different groups

Hopefully someone can help me get further!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select` must return something. You are not returning but only adding to an existing list. Do this instead:

```
var newList = Filtered.GroupBy(x => new { x.GroupName, x.PersonName }):

var result = new MultiKeyDictionary<string, string, int>);
foreach(var y in newList)
{
    result.Add(y.Key.GroupName, y.Key.PersonName, y.ToList().Count));    
}
```

The reason you are getting error below:

> "Cannot convert type 'void' to 'MultiKeyDictionary'

is because you are trying to cast the returned value from `Add` which is `void` to `MultiKeyDictionary<string,string,int>` which clearly cannot be done.

Comment: Thank you for the response! This actually worked and performance is way better again!

Answer (score 0):

If MultiKeyDictionary requires the two keys to match in order to find a result, then you might want to just use a regular `Dictionary` with a Tuple as a composite type. C# 7 has features that make this pretty easy:

```
public Dictionary<(string, string), int> GetPersonsPerGroup(IEnumerable<Home> homes ,List<string> gr, List<string> na)
{
    return Filtered.GroupBy(x => (x.GroupName, x.PersonName))
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count);
}
```

You can even associate optional compile-time names with your tuple's values, by declaring it like this: `Dictionary<(string groupName, string personName), int>`.

Comment: When implementing this code I get the following error:
    ´    Cannot convert lambda expresson to type 'IEqualityComparer<(string GroupName, string PersonName)>' because it is not a delegate type     ´ 
With the exceptions being ArgumentNullException and OverflowException. But I do not see what could be null here.

Answer (score 0):

Your grouping key anonymous object should work fine as a standard `Dictionary` key, so no reason to create a new type of `Dictionary` unless it offers special access via single keys, so just convert the grouping to a standard `Dictionary`:

```
var result = Filtered.GroupBy(f => new { f.GroupName, f.PersonName })
                     .ToDictionary(fg => fg.Key, fg => fg.Count());
```

Comment: When trying this I get a error saying:  'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.collections.Generic.dictionary<<anonymous type: string GroupName, string PersonName>, int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<(string groupName, string Personname),int>'.` 
It says that the exception thrown is a ArgumentNullException on the GroupBy() function. But I don't see how any of these values can be null (groupname and personname are not nullable types.

Comment: Your error shows you have an anonymous type from the code and a tuple type in the `result` variable, which implies you didn't use the code as written (specifically, you didn't use `var`).